# Distribute work with RabbiMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm using RabbitMQ and need a message to be queued and consumed by multiple servers, but only one of the servers could confirm this message and only it would remove this message from the queue, even if other servers have consumed the message, but do not have removed it from the queue. I wonder how RabbitMQ can do this scenario ?

Comment: Can you clarify why you would only need one consumer would be allowed to confirm the message? This sounds like a design issue, and would not be possible to implement using RabbitMQ.

Comment: Would this always be the same consumer confirming messages? If so you can have one master queue, and slave queues for the rest of the consumers.

Comment: Thank you @eandersson. I have some socket.io servers for realtiming with users and they can be connected to any of them, I'm not sticking them to a specific server. So I use rabbitmq to transport messages from an external API inside each socket.io server, so that I can receive a message from outside and send it to a specific client through socket.io. The point is, only the server which a client is connected to can confirm the message and remove it from the queue. A message must continue queued until a client confirms it, it does not matter which socket.io server was used to do it.

Comment: You probably want an RPC type pattern if that is the case. I don't think there is any other way of implementing this using RabbitMQ.

Comment: In fact, I ended up changing the subscribers so that they just do ack in a message that is useful for that particular server, otherwise I do a nack, which causes the message to be queued again and delivered to other subscribers. But there's a problem with this approach because a message will be delivered to all subscribers indefinitely until it is acked, and that would eat server's resources @eandersson